# angular js filter using moment js give wrong date ago

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I create filter to format date into times ago,like 2015-01-03 01:00:00 give  1 hours ago,
for  accomplish that i create angular filter as following.

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('from', function() {
  return function(date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
  }
});
```

When I apply it. withing my angular controller. as following

```
  {{2015-01-02 01:00:00 | from }}
```

Instead of given 1 days ago it give 45 years ago  i can't understand why

Comment: I don't think so, well you need to wrap them in quotes. http://plnkr.co/edit/Rk1XrBu3Dsg8dFl84NDo?p=preview

Comment: yes. is there any way to get 1 second ago  one hours ago instead  of   get 2 days ago

Comment: Since the original question is a typo marking for closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try qoute the date:

```
{{'2015-01-02 01:00:00' | from }}
```